# Replacing HTML code in python

Tags: python, html, regex, replace, tkinter

I'm using regular expressions to parse a website's source code and display a news headline in a `Tkinter` window. I have been told parsing HTML with regex isn't the best idea, but unfortunately do not have the time to change now.

I can't seem to be able to replace the HTML code for special characters such as apostrophe (`'`).

Currently I have the following:

```
union_url = 'http://www.news.com.au/sport/rugby'

def union():
    union_string = urlopen(union_url).read()
    union_string.replace("&#8217;", "'")
    union_headline = re.findall('(?:sport/rugby/.*) >(.*)<', union_string)
    union_headline_label= Label(union_window, text = union_headline[0], font=('Times',20,'bold'),  bg = 'White', width = 85, height = 3, wraplength = 500)
```

This doesn't get rid of HTML characters. As an example, headline prints as

```
Larkham: Real worth of &#8216;Giteau&#8217;s Law&#8217;
```

I have tried to find an answer without any luck. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to get data or parse data from html source??

Comment: sorry - get data to display on a tkinter widget

Comment: ever heard of [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) your life will be better with this... parsing HTML can be tough.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'callable' feature of re.sub() to unescape (or remove) anything escaped:

```
>>> import re
>>> def htmlUnescape(m):
...     return unichr(int(m.group(1), 16))
...
>>> re.sub('&#([^;]+);', htmlUnescape, "This is something &#8217; with an HTML-escaped character in it.")
u'This is something \u8217 with an HTML-escaped character in it.'
>>>
```